# apache tomcat connector for comet & jsp

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I am interested in deploying a tomcat7 server that will server JSP pages and also support comet.  I normally use the mod_jk connector for Apache/Tomcat communications.  I've found information that says not to use the mod_jk connector for comet.

My question is which connector is best for supporting Apache httpd/Tomcat comet & JSP?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/aio.html

APR or NIO HTTP connectors??

Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

YMMV and you should do your own tests, but:

we  recently switched from AJP to HTTP (2 lbs -> 7 tc in frontend-cluster) and found the HTTP-connector more stable when it comes to peak-times (we also found nginx slightly more stable than nginx, but apache offers a better balancer-management atm)

we also found  no sign for speed-improvemends for AJP vs HTTP, but you should do your own tests and YMMV